# Change array of images with NSTimer

Tags: objective-c

I want to implement a auto change image gallery. here is my code in the controller. i have a uiimageview named image. i want to link the array of image to my image view to let it auto change after a few seconds. What should i do??

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [self performSelector:@selector(changeImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
}

-(void)changeImage {
     NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"animated-fish-1.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"tumblr_7"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"th_nature_4.jpg"],nil];
     image.animationImages = images; 
     // how to let the array of image load and link to the perform selector??
     // what should i continue from here?
 }
```

Comment: you need to pass some imageName. It is good idea to store image name in a array or change all imagenames to image1.jpg, image2.jpg etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Store the images in an ivar

  ```
  @interface YourClass : SomeSuperClass

  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *images;

  @end
  ```
- Don't start the timer in `viewDidLoad` as the view will not be on the screen yet so there is no point - move it to `viewDidAppear:`

  ```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.images = @[ ... ]; // or pass these into the class
    self.imageView.image = self.images[0];
  }

  - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(changeImage:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
  }

  -(void)changeImage:(NSTimer *)timer
  {
    NSInteger currentIndex = [self.images indexOfObject:self.imageView.image];
    NSInteger nextIndex    = (currentIndex + 1) % self.images.count;

    self.imageView.image = self.images[nextIndex];

    // If for any reason you need to cancel the image rotation
    if ([self shouldCancelImageRotation]) {
      [timer invalidate];
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Hi paul. i tried using your code but there is an error.
Do you have any idea what is this error?

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<imageGalleryViewController 0x715b9e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image.'

Comment: Check the connections in your xib/storyboard you've probably broken one at some point by accident. Click on the `imageGalleryViewController` in your xib/storyboard then press ⌥⌘6 to shows the connections inspector. Now look for the `image` connection and fix it or remove it

Comment: hi paul. you are right i broke one of the connection. I solved that but it leads me to another error.


Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b18'

Comment: is it because of this?
self.images = @[@"image1.jpg",@"image2.jpg",@"image3.jpg",@"image4.jpg"];

Comment: Yup my examples assumes an array of images `self.images = @[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"], ... ]`

Answer (score 1):

To animate the images using timer, try this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(animateImages) 
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:YES];
        imageCount = 1;

 }

  -(void)animateImages
  {
         imageCount = imageCount + 1;
          NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i.png"];
          [theImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
    }
```

Comment: hi venky. how do you store an array of image into that nsstring?

Comment: Hi Benedict, You are not storing the image into string. Name the images in such a way image1, image2, image3, etc.. You are changing count value alone, which in turn will set the new image.

Answer (score 0):

You should use NSTimer, per example, you can use this method :

[https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval%3atarget%3aselector%3auserInfo%3arepeats%3a)

This method allow you to define a selector to use and repeats every x seconds

Answer (score 0):

try like this ,
take one global varaible  index

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad{
         [super viewDidLoad];
          index=0;
          NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"animated-fish-1.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"tumblr_7"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"th_nature_4.jpg"],nil];
imageview.image = [images objectAtIndex:index];
          [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }

-(void)changeImage {
      index++;
      if(index==[images count]){
        index=0;
     }
     imageview.image = [images objectAtIndex:index];
  }
```

Comment: Global variables are bad. Global variables are made worse with short names that don't mean anything :/